# Password protected download for community

Tags: webapp-rec, passwords, download, sharing

Our school has a document that they want to share with the parents of the school. We'd like to be able to send a link and password to the school's mailing list.

I know that this isn't the most secure way of doing things, but the key thing is that the document can't be on an unprotected link.

Can anybody recommend a site or utility that would allow us to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a free [Posterous](http://posterous.com) blog and set it to [private with a password](http://posterous.com/help/private_sites).

A Posterous blog is simple to update - in your case, you would send an email *with* a file attachment(s). Within seconds or minutes you get an email reply from posterous with a permalink to your new post which contains the download file.

In your school newsletter you mention that link and the site password.

Advantages over dropbox (also a great solution):

- If you need to change the group password, there is only one to change and all downloads will be protected under the new one immediately.
- Parents only have to deal with one password (and they'll have the checkbox option of Remember password the first time they go to get a download).
- Inherently, you get a history attachments (it's a blog after all).
- You'll be familiar with a solid blogging platform if and when it's time to migrate technology used for the (mass email) school newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but it might be useful to someone who reaches this page.

Both [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/5887) and [Box](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200519848-Can-I-password-protect-my-web-links-) offer this feature, albeit on paid plans. Or you could use [Passdropit](https://www.passdropit.com), which works on top of Dropbox and doesn’t require a paid plan.